# check if row mysql exist with php

Tags: php, mysql, synology

i'm trying to check if a row exist in my database using php, and the problem is that i can't understand what i wrong, this is the code:

```
while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        print "||" . $db_field['id_n']."||".$db_field['network_name']."||".$db_field['country']."||".$db_field['country_Name']."||"."<BR>";

        $query = "SELECT * FROM countries WHERE english_name='$db_field['country_Name']'";
        $doquery = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());   
        if (mysql_num_rows($doquery))
        {
            print 'Found';
        } else {
             print 'Not Found';
        }

    }
```

if i write these i receive no output, and also no error, i try to insert some print in the code at the start of my php or in the middle but no print is displayed, so i found that the error is in this line:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM countries WHERE english_name='$db_field['country_Name']'";
```

my question is, what is the error, and why display anything, i'd like it display an error or something else, or just print me the log i put in the code but nothing, seems that the php is blank, anyone can explain me these please?

Comment: Try wrapping your variable in brackets `$query = "SELECT * FROM countries WHERE english_name='{$db_field['country_Name']}'";`

Comment: enable error handling in php.ini

Comment: In addition, you have an sql injection problem, your query will break if the country is for example `people's republic of ...`. You should switch to PDO (or mysqli) and prepared statements or at the very least use `mysql_real_escape_string` on the value before you use it in the query.

Comment: Besides jeroen's advice, I recommend you to use a SQL join instead of one select statement per row, which is much slower.

Comment: thank you very much for the answers, with John Conde solution it works, i have installed phpmyadmin and web server  on my Nas Synology, you know where i can found php.ini?